# Debian 11 Setup fails with a shim_init() error

Tags: debian, uefi, debian-installer, bios

Basically I have the same problem as described here (https://linux.debian.user.narkive.com/csvu5OQJ/shim-init-error-for-debian-live-11-0-0-amd64-kde-iso) but I don't have a solution. The only difference is that I'm using the `firmware-11.0.0-amd64-netinst.iso` image. When I try to install Debian 11 on my Fujitsu Lifebook I'll get the error message

```
set_second_stage() failed: Invalid Parameter
Something has gone seriously wrong: shim_init() failed: Invalid Parameter
```

Shortly after that message, my PC turns itself off. Nothing else, just this message. I can't switch to a legacy BIOS mode. The only thing I could do is disabling secure boot, but this doesn't help. I created the USB stick using Rufus, UNetbootin and dd and it doesn't make a difference.

Does anybody has an idea how to fix this?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

I think you should install Debian 9 and then upgrade to 10 or 11.

I had the same error on my laptop Fujitsu Lifebook u938. I solved it by installing Debian 9 because Debian 9 doesn't have lib shim, whereas Debian 10 and 11 have it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but i had the same issue. I fixed it for me by swapping the EFI-Boot file (/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi) inside the bootable stick with one from a working iso (for me it was a linux mint iso, but you can use any working iso you like).

Hope this might fix it for you too.